# Not receiving firebase cloud messages sent via C#

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm having some strange behaviour between messages sent via a C# webserver to Firebase vs messages sent via RESTED / Postman

Using fiddler I create almost identical requests to Firebase (example below)

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Key=<OMITTED>
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 136

{"to":"/topics/NAME","notification":{ "text":"TEST","title":"TEST","click_action":null}}
```

When this is sent using an HTTP client in Chrome we receive the message immediately, but when we send it with C# using a webrequest we're not getting a message in response 100% of the time.

We receive a successful 200 response from Firebase regardless of method of sending and both contain a message id.

Answer (score 0):

OK! I feel really dumb now but it wasn't showing the notifications because the same domain sending the notifications was in the foreground, I switched to using a seperate browser to trigger them and it worked each time.

Comment: Great that it works. I thought it might be something with the payload structure since there seems to be a missing `{` just after `notification:`

Comment: Good spot - that was more a copy glitch though :)